# Clickhouse install on Ubuntu 16.04 failing

Tags: clickhouse

Much appreciated if someone tells me how to install on Ubuntu 16.04.
I've tried this:

Steps I took:
echo "deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/trusty stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E0C56BD4    # optional

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install clickhouse-client clickhouse-server-common

Errors:

root@c-2:~# sudo apt-get install clickhouse-client clickhouse-server-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clickhouse-client : Depends: clickhouse-server-base (= 1.1.54245) but it is not going to be installed
 clickhouse-server-common : Depends: clickhouse-server-base (= 1.1.54245) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/xenial stable main
```

Its literally in the line bellow where you copy pasted from in the docs:

```
For other Ubuntu versions, replace trusty to xenial or precise.
```

Version 16.x = xenial

... though it would be nice if they just renamed the paths to 12.x, 14.x and 16.x instead of using code names.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
echo "deb https://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/stable main/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E0C56BD4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clickhouse-client clickhouse-server
```

I use **https** which is working. http not working in deb